# How do i display the catch exception?

Tags: android, android-logcat

I just want to ask how do i display the catch exception in android so that i will know if my application catching some error..
example on this.

```
try {
    my codes here.....
} catch (IOException e) {
    //how do i dpslay  the exception        
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
try {
  // my codes here.....
} catch(IOException e){
  Log.d("MY_APP", "---------------------"); //separator from other logs (optional)
  e.printStackTrace();
  Log.d("MY_APP", "---------------------"); //separator from other logs (optional)
}
```

Comment: by the way does the system.out.print("some error") will work in android?,thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: `System.out.print("TEST");` actually print out **TEST** in Console Log (not LogCat)

Comment: `System.out` etc will work fine but I would rather use one of the `Log` methods (e.g. `Log.e("MY_APP", "Oh no, it's that IO problem again", e)` that take exceptions as 3rd parameter. You can set the tag that way.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want some visual (UI) representation of errors.
You can display your errors with `Toast`, for example.
Or use some library like `Crouton`. See http://johnkil.github.io/Android-AppMsg/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Toast` class for instance:

```
...
catch (IOException e) {
   Toast.makeText(<context>, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show();  
   // or use Log class like Log.e("From class X", e.getMessage());   
}
```

Note if  that piece of code is invoked from background Thread you cannot show that message for that that Thread.

In this scenario you need to use another mechanism (runOnUiThread(), Handler, AsyncTask, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this...This might help you..

```
try {
    my codes here.....
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("e", "exception", e);
}
```